# How to use Kalman Filter Theorm to calculate next event date

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, kalman-filter

I am having a problem statement which requires that if a particular error/event happens on

```
1-Jan-2017 and then on 
22-Feb-2017,
3-April-2017,
9-July-2017
```

so i have to **predict that when the next event is gonna occur** , I am planning to try it with **Kalman Filter theorm** but it has very statistical terms and on the internet I didn't found any easy explanation or easy programming example for Kalman filter algorithm which estimates the next event dates . Can someone **explain in simple terms** or any ***parellel algorithm*** which can be used for the same purpose ?

Comment: Can you be more precise about what you mean by "predict"?  Do you need a probability distribution for possible times, or just an expected value?

Comment: More spcifically a expected value or expected series of dates

Comment: An expected value means that you have modelled the probability distribution, as pointed out by @pjs. Currently, the way you expose the problem is similar to saying I have this list of numbers:  56, 143, -345, 235, 897, 2222222222222, 0.7. What is next? Unless you have a either a function that telles you f(1)=56, f(2)=143, etc, or, a recursive one like f(i)=g(f(1),...,f(i-1)),  there is not much you can do except try to fit a distribution to your data. In your case all I can think of is the Poisson distribution, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Ash I'm afraid you've put words into my mouth that I didn't say.  An expected value does **not** mean that you have modeled the probability distribution, which is why I was asking if expectation was sufficient.  The sample mean is an unbiased estimator of the expected value, regardless of the distribution.  Please see my answer for how this might be leveraged if expected values are all that's needed.

Comment: Thank you for correcting me. My deepest apologies to you and OP for my wrong statements.

Comment: @Ash No need to apologize, but deleting comments is always an option if you have regrets about them.

Answer (score 3):

Let E<sub>i</sub> be the i<sup>th</sup> event, and let IET<sub>i</sub> = E<sub>i+1</sub> - E<sub>i</sub> be the i<sup>th</sup> Inter-Event Time, i.e., the time between one event and the next.  Then E<sub>i+1</sub> = E<sub>i</sub> + IET<sub>i</sub> — the next event can be forecast from the most recent event based on IET.

Since the past is already determined the only thing random when you're projecting the next event is IET, so E[E<sub>i+1</sub>] = E<sub>i</sub> + E[IET<sub>i</sub>] (where E[] denotes a common notation for expected value). You don't need to know the distribution of IET to estimate its expected value, you only need to assume that the IETs are identically distributed. (They don't even need to be independent.) In other words, if IETs are identically distributed then the average of historical IETs is an unbiased estimator of their expected value.

There is a simple Kalman filter estimator to update estimates of an average as you obtain new data. See equations (2) & (3) from [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1137342) on math.stackexchange.

Note that this approach just gives a point predictor for the expected value.  It won't allow you to make any probability statements about how likely it is the next event happens before or after some specified date.  To do that you would need distributional information about the IETs.

Comment: Thanks again for correcting my comment. I'd like to ask two questions if you don't mind: **1)** If I understand correctly, equations (2) and (3) from the post you linked to is just a running average, right? **2)** Although the equations that are derived at the end of the post exactly look like Kalman's, isn't the Gaussian assumption on the state vector necessary? Without this assumption, why still call it a Kalman filter?

Comment: @Ash 1) - Yup.  2) - From paragraph 4 of the [Wikipedia article on Kalman Filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter): "The Kalman filter does not make any assumption that the errors are Gaussian."  People often like to assume Gaussian errors, because then you can make probability claims about the conditional predictions.

Comment: Thanks again. I know that I am probably abusing of your kindness, but would it be possible if I asked you a few questions via mail? They are related to comparisons between two families of techniques for state estimation in the simultaneous localization and mapping litterature. If you'd grant me the honor, my mail adress is given on my profile page.

Comment: @Ash I have no expertise in the area you're talking about, and would prefer to stick with StackOverflow for my communications.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** Thanks to @pjs for his remarks. I will update my answer accordingly as soon as I can. However, many authors in the robotics/computer vision communities (*e.g.* [Thrun et al](http://www.probabilistic-robotics.org/)) seem to directly define Kalman filters as Gaussian filters (and for those that are familiar with the computer vision/SLAM litterature, some computer vision works seem to discard standard EKF-based SLAM Since the Gaussian assumption doesn't hold for 3d points). In @pmj's answer, the Gaussian filter is actually nothing more than a running average and doesn't provide covariance (which can in some applications, be considered as the only justification for using a Kalman filter instead of non-linear minimizations on an equivalent cost-function) , so it seems pretty useless without an assumption on the distribution... So I wonder if this is what motivates said authors choices, or if it is just to simplify the discussion.

---

I think that Kalman filtering has very little to do with what you want to achieve. I will detail why after briefly explaining, in simple terms, what a Kalman filter does.

A Kalman filter estimates the current state `x_t` of a dynamic system based on all the previous observations, or in more mathematical terms, it models the probability distribution

```
p(x_t|z_1,...,z_t)
```

where the `z_i` are you observations (*i.e* measurements). Moreover, it is designed with a Gaussian assumption in mind. That is, it assumes that the distribution of your state/errors, including the one above, are Gaussian. Furthermore, it requires a model that links the measurements to the states, something like

```
z_t=f(x_t)+some_gaussian_noise
```

and you alos need a transition model, that links the previous state with the current one, *e.g.*

```
x_t=g(x_{t-1})+some_gaussian_noise
```

This comes with the assumption of having a "complete state": the knowledge of the current state is taken to be enough to predict the next one.

**So, this is why I think it won't work with your model:**

- Given the information you've given, I see no sign that you can assume the distribution of the events is Gaussian. Its is probably not.
- You don't have any transition equation, I don't even think it is possible to define one for your problem. Moreover, state completion doesn't hold.
- Your state, as well as its observations, seem to be discrete, while Kalman filters are designed with continuous parameter spaces in mind.

Unfortunately, you haven't provided much information, so I can only suggest that you model your problem as a Markov chain, which I think you already had thought about.

Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: I don't have a copy of the book, but looking at the PPT on the web page you linked Thrun et al. don't define Kalman filters as having Gaussian errors, they ***assume*** Gaussian errors to be able to go on and use Kalman filtering as a Gaussian filter.  You might find [this paper](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/nav.21628/full) interesting. It's got a different context, but discusses the hazards of making unwarranted assumptions just to get mathematical tractability.

Comment: At the end of the day, though, Thrun et al. don't get to define what a Kalman filter is.  That privilege belongs to Kalman, who said in his 1960 paper that no Gaussian (or other distributional) assumption is required.

Comment: With regards to your comments in the **Edit**, I've explained in my answer that the average is an unbiased estimator of the mean regardless of the distribution and does not require independent observations, so the covariance structure is irrelevant when using an average to estimate the mean.  What "motivates" my answer is that it directly addresses the question that was asked, without any need for additional assumptions you seem to want to impose.  I haven't simplified anything, but rather have avoided needless complications.

Comment: @pmj Anyone reading this will see that your answer is more relevant than mine, and that this is the best that one can do given the information OP provides. What I meant was that I think that it would be better for OP to redefine his problem, because, in any realistic setting, a running average would be of little use (imagine if these predicted dates were sensor failure!). I will try to edit my answer as soon as I can, so that it is aligned to your remarks. Thanks for the paper, by the way :)

Comment: You're welcome on the paper.  Idle curiosity - why do you refer to me as pmj?

Comment: @pjs ooops. Sorry. I've been listening to pmj (post-modern juke box, a youtube channel that turns simple, often extremly simple popular music into oldschool jazz with lots of cool scatsinging, tapdance and whatnot) while on stackoverflow. So, everytime I just replaced you name with this acronym. I even thought it was a cool coincidence. Guess I'm developping some sort of dyslexia!